# Разделение одной строки из файла на четыре разных переменных - Java

Tags: java

Друзья, моя задача следующая, в файле у меня есть только одна строка - `10.0 20.0 30.0 40.0`.
Я должен каждое число типа double здесь присвоить для соответствующей переменной, но на выходе
где высветляю в консоль переменные:

```
    System.out.print(x + "\n");
    System.out.print(y + "\n");
    System.out.print(szerokosc + "\n");
    System.out.print(wysokosc + "\n");
```

я получаю следующее:

```
10.0
20.0
20.0
20.0
```

Задумkа в моем коде следующая, я буду переберать эту строку 4 раза, и в каждом цикле буду
присваевать нужное значение в нужную переменную. В первом цикле я буду переберать каждый символ
строки до тех пор пока не наткнусь на пробел, и в переменную записываю все символы до пробела.
В след. циклах тоже самое только начиная с позиции после первого числа, делаю это с помощью
`i = первоеЧисло.длина() + 1`. То есть пропускаю первое число и плюс пропускаю пробел.
Вот такая задумка, не понимаю почему это не работает, буду рад за подсказки! Вот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("dane.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String wiersz;
            String X = "", Y = "", SZEROKOSC = "", WYSOKOSC = "";
            double x = 0, y = 0, szerokosc = 0, wysokosc = 0;
            while ((wiersz = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < wiersz.length(); i++) {
                    if (wiersz.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        X = X + wiersz.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = X.length() + 1; i < wiersz.length(); i++) {
                    if (wiersz.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        Y = Y + wiersz.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = Y.length() + 1; i < wiersz.length(); i++) {
                    if (wiersz.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        SZEROKOSC = SZEROKOSC + wiersz.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = SZEROKOSC.length() + 1; i < wiersz.length(); i++) {
                    if (wiersz.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        WYSOKOSC = WYSOKOSC + wiersz.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                x = Double.parseDouble(X);
                y = Double.parseDouble(Y);
                szerokosc = Double.parseDouble(SZEROKOSC);
                wysokosc = Double.parseDouble(WYSOKOSC);

                System.out.print(x + "\n");
                System.out.print(y + "\n");
                System.out.print(szerokosc + "\n");
                System.out.print(wysokosc + "\n");

                X = "";
                Y = "";
                SZEROKOSC = "";
                WYSOKOSC = "";
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            System.out.print("Blad: " + exc);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

код круто, но лучше все таки воспользоваться тем, что уже есть - `java.util.Scanner`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("dane.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        double x = scanner.nextDouble();
        double y = scanner.nextDouble();
        double z = scanner.nextDouble();
        double v = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(x); // 10.0
        System.out.println(y); // 20.0
        System.out.println(z); // 30.0
        System.out.println(v); // 40.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Andrew Bystrov переиграл и уничтожил.

Comment: Но я, все же надеюсь, что мне кто-то поможет с моим кодом)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Самый простой выход - это разделить строку по пробелу.
String[] arr = bufferedReader.readLine().split(" ");
// Потом просто парсим каждую строку в double и сохраняем в отдельную переменную
double x = Double.parseDouble(arr[0]);
double y = Double.parseDouble(arr[1]);
double szerokosc = Double.parseDouble(arr[2]);
double wysokosc = Double.parseDouble(arr[3]);
```